# Mock smart contract solidity - can't deploy mock smart contract - TypeError: Contract "mockMyToken" should be marked as abstract

Tags: mocking, solidity, erc20, openzeppelin

I wrote a smart contract that uses openzepplin ERC20 standard. I am able to deploy it using truffle and my tests work as expected. I am now trying to test part of the code that is dependent on time (`block.number`) For the purpose of allowing the user to mint once every 24 hours.

In order to mock the time in a test I am following this pattern outlined here https://dappsdev.org/hands-on/testing/solidity-mocks/

```
 contract myToken is ERC20 {
   // generic implementation of token here

   // mockContract is going to override this
  function getTime() internal virtual view returns (uint256) {
        return block.timestamp;
    }

}

contract mockMyToken is myToken {
    uint256 public fakeBlockTimeStamp;

    function getTime() internal override(myToken) view returns (uint256) {
        return fakeBlockTimeStamp;
    }

    function _mock_setBlockTimeStamp(uint256 value) public {
        fakeBlockTimeStamp = value;
    }
}
```

When I run `truffle test` I am getting `TypeError: Contract “mockMyToken" should be marked as abstract` but I want to deploy mockMyToken so by adding `abstract` to it makes it non deployable. This error does not make sense to me if anything, myToken should be the abstract contract (I've also tried this).

How can I mock the same way as  https://dappsdev.org/hands-on/testing/solidity-mocks/
They do not use any abstract keyword.